# Execute the class on timer basis in mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, background-thread

I am using Asp.net MVC3 where I want to run a class on timely basis, say start of every month,  without any human intervention, more of like making it an automated process. Right now I am confused between which approach to follow :

1. Running a background thread to start that class
2. Creating a windows service for it.

I would much appreciate if anyone would guide me through this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why dont you make a windows scheduled task and run the class from there

Comment: windows service all the way, you can use quartz to schedule it to run.  Have implemented a few services like that.